# In the WiX toolset, how do I let the user modify a path read from the registry?

Tags: wix

My application is reading databases (known as "Sites") from a directory ("SITEDIR"). During the installation I want the installer to read the directory's path set by the previous version in the Registry (if it exists) and then let the user modify that path if they want to.

My problem is that the value I read from the Registry overrides the value set by the user.

How do I make sure that the value set by the user is the one the installer will use?

This is my code:

```
<!-- Set the USER_SITEDIR property to the default value before reading the value from the Registry, in case there is no previous version installed . -->
<Property Id="USER_SITEDIR" Value="C:\User Sites"/>

<!-- Read the Sites Directory from the registry. If the key doesn't exist, the property will be null. If the directory doesn't exist, the property will be set to C:\-->
<Property Id="REG_SITEDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="RegSearchSiteDir" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)\$(var.PrevVersion)\Directories" Name="Site Directories" Type="directory" />          
</Property>

<!-- Set the SITEDIR directory to the value read from the registry, only if that value has been set -->
<SetProperty Id="USER_SITEDIR" After="AppSearch" Value="[REG_SITEDIR]">
  REG_SITEDIR
</SetProperty>

<!-- finally, set the directory's name to the one read from the Registry -->
<SetDirectory Id="SITEDIR" Value="[USER_SITEDIR]"/>


<!-- This is somewhat of a "dummy" feature. It's only here to let the users define the databases location-->
<Feature Id="Databases" Title ="Databases" Level="1" Absent="disallow" Description="Location of your databases" ConfigurableDirectory="SITEDIR"/>
```

Example:

The default value of SITEDIR is "C:\Sites".
The initial value of the property USER_SITEDIR is "C:\User Sites"
The previous version had the "Site Directories" key set to "C:\Sites Old".

During installation, at the CustomizeDlg dialog, the folder shown for the "Databases" feature is "C:\Sites Old".
I click "Browse..." and change the folder to "C:\Sites New".

I expect the sites to be copied into "C:\Sites New", and the value of the "Directories" Registry key for the installed version to be "C:\Sites New" as well.

However, the actual result is that the files are copied into "C:\Sites Old", and the Registry key points to that path as well.

If there is no previously installed version, the files are copied into "C:\User Sites" (The value of USER_SITES).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found an answer.
Not sure if it's the proper way of doing it, but it works.

Looking at the installation logs, I realised the reason the value was overwritten is that after the CustomizeDlg dialog the installer was calling the "AppSearch" action once more, which invoked reading the value from the Registry and setting it to SITEDIR once more.

To prevent that I added another property called "SITEDIR_SET", and set its value to "1"
after the action "FileCost". Additionally, I added the condition "NOT SITEDIR_SET" to the code setting SITEDIR.
"FileCost" is triggered right after the first time setSITEDIR was called, so SITEDIR was set once and that's it.

Here's how the code looks:

```
<Property Id="SITEDIR_SET" />

<!-- Read the Sites Directory from the registry. If the key or the directory don't exist, the property will not be set.-->
<Property Id="REG_SITEDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="RegSearchSiteDir" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)\$(var.PrevVersion)\Directories" Name="Site Directories" Type="directory" />
</Property>

<!-- Set the SITEDIR directory to the value read from the registry, only if that value has been set -->
<SetProperty Id="USER_SITEDIR" After="AppSearch" Value="[REG_SITEDIR]" >
  REG_SITEDIR
</SetProperty>

<!-- finally, set the directory's name to the one read from the Registry if is hasn't already been set -->
<SetDirectory Id="SITEDIR" Value="[USER_SITEDIR]" >
  NOT SITEDIR_SET
</SetDirectory>

<!-- Flag used to stop WiX from resetting SITEDIR's value. The FileCost action happens right after setting SITEDIR for the first time -->
<SetProperty Id="SITEDIR_SET" After ="FileCost" Value="1" />
```